# in tf_upgrade_v2 module, 'cp949' codec error comes out

Tags: tensorflow

I'm migrating my tensorflow v1 code to v2 code as follows

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --infile Untitled1.ipynb --outfile tensorfoo-upgraded.py
```

but

```
'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 295: illegal multibyte sequence
```

comes out. I noticed this is error of windows, because my ipynb is encoded as utf-8. not ansi.
I recreated my ipynb via jupyter notebook, but seems it still encoded as utf-8.
Is there any solution to utf-8 encoding error in tf_upgrade_v2?

```
Extracting code lines from original notebook
2020-04-06 17:20:06.360581: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\tf_upgrade_v2.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py", line 147, in main
    args.input_file, output_file, upgrade)
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py", line 47, in process_file
    ipynb.process_file(in_filename, out_filename, upgrader)
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\ipynb.py", line 43, in process_file
    raw_code, notebook = _get_code(in_filename)
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\ipynb.py", line 113, in _get_code
    notebook = json.load(in_file)
  File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 295: illegal multibyte sequence
```